# What does squaring a vector mean?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, geometry, speed

So,in the 3rd equation of motion,i.e $v²=u²+2as$,what does the square on the final velocity and initial velocity actually mean?And how does it make an effect on their direction?

**suppose upwards vector is positive and downwards vector is negative**.And,we are throwing a ball from a height of h from ground.In this case,u=-4m/s and there is some final velocity downwards

While using $v²=u²+2as$ here, $u$ is -4m/s and so $u²$ will be 16(m/s)^2. Doesnt this change its direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$v^2 = v \cdot v$ - where $\cdot$ indicates the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

The result of the dot product is a scalar, not a vector; it doesn't have a direction.

Example for your vector: $\vec{u} = 0 \vec{i} - 4 \vec{j} + 0 \vec{k}$, because $u$ is completely in the vertical direction and there is no component in the horizontal or perpendicular directions. Then $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{u} = 0 \vec{i} \cdot \vec{i} + 16 \vec{j} \cdot \vec{j} + 0 \vec{k} \cdot \vec{k} = 16$, since the unit vectors dot themselves $= 1$ (make sure you understand why this is the case). 16 is a scalar, it is no longer a vector, as you can see from the fact that it doesn't have $\vec{i}, \vec{j}$, or $\vec{k}$.

Comment: Not just any scalar. $v^{2} = \|v\|^{2}$, because Euclidean space is an inner product space.

Comment: Thanks.Isnt this the only scalar valued SUVAT equation?

Comment: @RehanaParvin yes, the others are all vectors. (In principle. At high school level, they're often treated as scalars.)

Answer (score 5):

$v^2=u^2-2as$ is usually presented as a formula that applies to one-dimensional motion with constant acceleration $a$ - in this version $u,v,a,s$ are all scalar quantities so multiplying them is not a problem.

However, there is a vector version of this formula which applies to motion in any number of dimensions, where multiplications are replaced by dot products:

$\vec v \cdot \vec v = \vec u \cdot \vec u + 2 \vec a \cdot \vec s$

In this case the acceleration $\vec a$ is assumed to be a constant vector.

Comment: why are v,u,a and s considered scalars in 1d motion?

Comment: @RehanaParvin Because a one-dimensional vector *is* a scalar.

Comment: @RehanaParvin actually is a pseudoscalar, since it changes sign under coordinate inversion.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is elegantly confusing with a deeper hidden meaning.

#### Explanation of the formula

Given the initial velocity of an object and its acceleration, plus its displacement, we can figure out the velocity of the object at that specific position in **all moments of time.**

#### Your confusion

In your case , the final velocity at any given position(or displacement) specified by you, is the same even if you throw the ball upwards (+ve) or downwards (-ve). This is because this formula *doesn't include **time*** as a parameter.

Hope it helps!

Comment: so should I include the direction in the answer with it's sign ?

Comment: The answer to what question?

Comment: This-"Find the final velocity"

Comment: I assume you are confused with the square root. I think ur asking whether you should take the positive or negative square root to find v. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: This equation does not provide the velocity as a vector, just it's magnitude. You have to find the direction by other means.

Comment: As @nasu correctly pointed out, if the object is moving in the direction of displacement, then the velocity will be positive. If it is moving opposite to the displacement, the velocity is negative. In both cases, we have to assign the sign depending upon the case

Comment: The velocity is always in the direction of displacement. The sign is just a matter of how you choose the coordinate axis

Answer (score -1):

This equation should be written:
$$
v_{x}^2 = v_{0x}^2 + 2 a_x (x - x_0)\,,
$$
where $v_x = v_x(t) = \vec{v}(t) \cdot \hat{i}$ and $x = x(t) = \vec{r}(t) \cdot \hat{i}$, meaning that it is an equation for the components of the vectors, under the assumption of constant acceleration vector, $\vec{a}$, and a choice of coordinate system.

To see that this is true, recall that the basic equations of motion for a constant acceleration vector are:
\begin{align*}
\vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}(0) + \vec{v}(t) \,t + \frac{1}{2} \vec{a} t^2\\
\vec{v}(t) &= \vec{v}(0) + \vec{a} t
\end{align*}
which are found by integrating $\frac{{\rm d}^2 \vec{r}}{{\rm d} t^2} = \vec{a}$ twice. What is true for these vector equations is also true for any component of the vectors, under any choice of coordinate system.  So, given such a choice, we have the following equations for the $x$ components of the vectors:
\begin{align*}
x &= x_0 + v_x t + \frac{1}{2} a_x t^2\\
v_x &= v_{0x} + a_x t 
\end{align*}
where I've suppressed the time dependence of $x$ and $v_x$ and written $x_0 = x(0)$ and $v_{0x} = v_x(0)$.

We can do algebra on these two component equations to eliminate time and obtain an equation that relates the $x$ components of velocity and position. Namely, multiplying the first equation by $2 a_x$, we obtain
$$
2 a_x (x - x_0) = 2 a_x v_{0x} t + a_x^2 t^2
$$
and then squaring $(v_x - v_{0x})$ in the second equation and inserting the second equation again:
\begin{align*}
(v_x - v_{0x})^2 &= a_x^2 t^2 \\
v_x^2 - 2 v_x v_{0x} + v_{0x}^2 &= a_x^2 t^2\\
v_x^2 + v_{0x}^2 - 2 (v_{0x} + a_x t) v_{0x} &= a_x^2 t^2\\
v_x^2 - v_{0x}^2 = 2 a_x v_{0x} t + a_x^2 t^2
\end{align*}
and finally inserting our first result into this second result we obtain:
$$
v_x^2 - v_{0x}^2 = 2 a_x (x - x_0)\,.
$$

So the equation you are presenting is actually an equation for the components of the position, velocity, and acceleration vectors along any chosen direction (again, under the assumption that the acceleration vector is constant).  The vector equation version presented above in gandalf61's answer is obtained by summing the $x$, $y$, and $z$ versions of this equation together, but this component equation cannot be determined from that vector equation.

Comment: It is an equation for the magnitude of the component of the vector. You cannot find the sign of the component from this equation

Comment: No, that is not true. Each of those variables are components as I have written.  In particular, the values of $a_x$, $x$, and $x_0$ could be positive or negative depending on your choice of coordinate system.  It is true that, because the velocity component only shows up as a square, that you can only solve for $|v_x|$.

Comment: But you cannot find their sign from this equation.